# CSS Dropdown Menu snaps/resizes on hover

Tags: css, menu

Today I was trying to learn how to create those triangles with CSS Borders and I finally did. Awesome stuff! Although it seems that whenever I hover over the menu two things happen that I want to fix (1) the menu seems to snap and resize on hover and resize back on mouse out. (2) the hover opacity seems to flow down to the first item of the sub-menu. I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dani0157/2xk0eo12/) over here. If anyone can drop some knowledge on me, I'd be very grateful!

### HTMLCode

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navContainer">
<ul class="nav group">
<li>
<a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
<ul class="subNav group">
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="active">
<a class="active" href="#">Safari</a>
<ul class="subNav group">
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="active">
<a class="active" href="#">Prices</a>
<ul class="subNav group">
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="active">
<a class="active" href="#">Photos</a>
<ul class="subNav group">
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="active">
<a class="active" href="#">Contact</a>
<ul class="subNav group">
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="box"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

### CSS Code

```
html {
font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
background: #fff;
font-size: 1.6em;  
}

.navContainer {
width: 1100px; 
margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
left:30%;
font-size: 1.3rem;


}

li {
float: left;
list-style-type:none;
text-align: center;
background: #aa2929;


}

li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
padding: 1rem 2rem; 
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;

}

li a:focus,
li a:hover {
color: #fff;
background: #a85555;
background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.15); 
}

ul.subNav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul.subNav li {
float: none;
display: none;

}

.nav li:hover ul.subNav li  {
display: block;
}

.group:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}

li a.active:hover:after {
content: "";
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width: 0; 
height: 0;
border-left: 7px solid transparent;
border-right: 7px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(89, 172, 255, 0.83);
}
```

Comment: You have to position the subnav `ul` absolutely

Answer (score 1):

It's because your "Sub-Items" are wider than your main nav elements, so when you hover and the Sub-Items are shown, the parent (main nav element) has to expand to fit it.

Putting a fixed width on `.nav.group > li` should solve your problem.

Another option is to absolute-position the dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

position absolute on your subNav and a fixed width on the parent list items ( .nav li) will fix the issue

```
.nav li{
    width:80px; /* I used 80px as example */
}
.subNav{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Add the above to the base of your css it will fix it.

Code Snippet...

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
.navContainer {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #aa2929;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
li a:focus,
li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #a85555;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
ul.subNav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.subNav li {
  float: none;
  display: none;
}
.nav li:hover ul.subNav li {
  display: block;
}
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
li a.active:hover:after {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(89, 172, 255, 0.83);
}
.nav li {
  width: 80px;
}
.subNav {
  position: absolute;
}
.nav > li > a {
  height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navContainer">
    <ul class="nav group">
      <li>
        <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
        <ul class="subNav group">
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a class="active" href="#">Safari</a>
        <ul class="subNav group">
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a class="active" href="#">Prices</a>
        <ul class="subNav group">
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a class="active" href="#">Photos</a>
        <ul class="subNav group">
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a class="active" href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul class="subNav group">
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes that helps. Thanks! Though when you hover over a top-level li you still see the hover effect flow down a little bit to the sub-nav.

Comment: @Dani - The reason the sub menus were jumping a bit is because the :after content takes up about 8px in height and only appears when hovering over the .nav menu and the moment you hover away from the .nav element to the subnav element the 8px height disappears giving you the jumping effect. I added a height attribute that will affect only the .nav li a element ( check updated code snippet). Hope this is what you were looking for